# MFC application exception handling weird behaviour

Tags: exception, mfc, crash, report, try-catch

I have a 64bit MFC application, in which I use crash reporting. The method is based on this article:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/debug/XCrashReportPt1.aspx?display=Print
So I have a __try - __except wrapper frame around `AfxWinMain`.
Last year it seemed to work well (I mean on different operating systems and also with 32 bit and 64 bit application).
Let's take this exception providing code part:

```
    void CMyDig::Foo()
    {
        std::vector<int> v;
        int i = v.at(42);
    }
```

When I write this code inside a dialog's message-handler, for example a button's clickhandler called Foo, then the exception is not caught in `AfxWinMain`.
If I write the same to a global function, it passes the exception to `AfxWinMain`.
Now we have this strange issue:
On some computers the dialog's case also generates the crash report(enters the __except block in afxwinmain), but others no. I managed to create a crash report on win7 64-bit, but the same program on win8, win8.1 and another win7 64bit doesn't make the report!
I compile with vs2010, and in code generation options, the "enable c++ exceptions" is set to EHsc (as last year, when it was working well).

Thanks for any ideas!
Attila

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't be easier to just define [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create the crash report.

In this case you don't need such a __try / __except block

WndProcs have their own __try __except blocks and some of the exceptions are handled by themselves.
But anyhow. I never had problems with an exception filter. 
My routines usually create a crash dump (minidump) and terminate. I always felt that this bare information is never enough for our technical stuff to find problems.

Comment: Thank you! You pointed the right method, and it seems to work for me! I used this guide, too: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/154686/SetUnhandledExceptionFilter-and-the-C-C-Runtime-Li